# iOS 13: Twitter login not redirecting back to application

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, swift5, xcode11

Xcode version: 11.2.1,
Swift version: 5,
iOS version: 13*

I have implemented twitter login integration as per twitter documentation with proper callback, URL Scheme and app delegate methods. When I am running code on iOS 12.4 device it's working perfectly. But on iOS 13 device it is not redirecting back to app. I guess there is some issue with scene delegate but I am not able figure out exact issue.

Here's the code

**App delegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey: "consumer key", consumerSecret: "consumer secret key")
    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let directedByFB = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    let directedByTWTR =  TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
    let directedByGGL = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.handle(url) ?? false
    return directedByGGL || directedByTWTR || directedByFB
}
```

**Call back url**
twitterkit-consumerKey://

**URL Scheme**
twitterkit-consumerKey

**View controller code**

```
TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn(completion: { (session, error) in
        if let twitterSession = session {
            let credential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(withToken: twitterSession.authToken, secret: twitterSession.authTokenSecret)
        }
    })
```

Comment: did you find a solution? @Rohit Jain

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that this Twitter no longer supporting TWTRTwitter and I suggest you to find another solution to implement Twitter Login in your application.

First of all you need to translate SceneDelegate's **func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set)** to work with Legacy Twitter library.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
if let openURLContext = URLContexts.first{
  let url = openURLContext.url
  let options: [AnyHashable : Any] = [
    UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation : openURLContext.options.annotation,
    UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication : openURLContext.options.sourceApplication,
    UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.openInPlace : openURLContext.options.openInPlace
  ]
  TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: options)
}
```

}

Finally, as Geet stated, don't forget to dismiss presented Twitter Login ViewController after login completed

```
TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn(with: viewController, completion: { [weak self] (session, error) in
    viewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}
```

Cheers

Comment: This helps me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add self.dismiss in TWTRTwitter login method. It helped me.

```
        TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn(with: self) { (session, error) in
        if (session != nil) {
               print("signed in as \(String(describing: session?.userName))");

            self.dismiss(animated: true) {
                print("Logged in ")
            }
               let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()

               client.requestEmail { email, error in
                   var emailStr = ""
                   if (email != nil) {
                       emailStr = email!
                   } else {
                       print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
                   }


                if let userName = session?.userName {
                    let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: session!.userID)
                    client.loadUser(withID: session!.userID) { (unwrappedTwtrUser, error) in
                            guard let twtrUser = unwrappedTwtrUser, error == nil else {
                                print("Twitter : TwTRUser is nil, or error has occured: ")
                                print("Twitter error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                                return
                            }
                            let name = twtrUser.name
                            let imageUrl = twtrUser.profileImageMiniURL
                            let token = session!.authToken
                        }


                }

            }
        } else {
            print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")");
        }
```